# How to Embed a Form within another Form in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In an internet webpage , there is a constant menu usually placed on the top  or left of a page  from which user can navigate (They call it Iframes) ..

I would like to know if it is possible to do something like that using WinForm applications or WPF applications in c# .

At present  I am simply inheriting forms from a base class . and each time  the user needs to navigate , I have no option but to open up a new form with  the same Peristent menu ...

Any suggestions here ?

Comment: I think you mean frames, not iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to use  usercontrol to embed a form into another ..

Form1 has a userControl ,  Form2 embedded inside the user control .

things to note was .. 
the embedded forms toplevel property should be set to false
the embedded forms FormBorderStyle should be set to none

```
userControl1.Controls.Clear();
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.Toplevel=flase;
f.Show();
f.TopLevel = false;
userControl1.Controls.Add(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like an MDI application (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/myBestMDI.aspx) or just using a SplitContainer on the form?  Really there are many options.  WPF has ElementHost I think.  Did you do any research yet?  What did you find?

You could also take the toolbox approach.  Have a parent program start the menu form and then other forms can use it... or it can launch from it... what ever your use case is.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an MDI-container in WinForms.
see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4dabts7.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76.aspx) for more information.

Comment: thannks Koen , I  have to mention that I got an Idea from  the links you suggested .

Answer (score 0):

Well, there should be a frame component in WPF which will give you such an option. Then you would use a "view" concept to open the WPF Pages you direct the user to.